# ros gazebo real time factor

Tags: ros

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

I want to use the real time simulate ,I know launch the world with ros by include a world .and  I have set the physics as follow (empty_world.launch)

> version="1.5">   
>
>
> model://sun
>
> ```
> </include>
> <!-- A ground plane -->
> <include>
>   <uri>model://ground_plane</uri>
> </include>
>    ***<physics type='ode'>
>   <max_step_size>0.001</max_step_size>
>   <real_time_factor>1</real_time_factor>
>   <real_time_update_rate>1000</real_time_update_rate>
>   <gravity>0 0 -9.8</gravity>
> </physics>***
> ```

the question is that when Iaunch the world only ,the real time factor(RTF)can be 1,but when I spawn my own urdf or xacro robot ,the RTF while be changed .

I don't know how to handle it.

I use gazebo 7 ros kinetic  the launch file as follow

> (I try to set
> true and false didn't work)      
>       type="static_transform_publisher"
> args="0 0 0 0 0 0 base_link base_footprint 40" />

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/18075/ros-gazebo-real-time-factor/) by [linus111](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4081/linus111/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-12-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Mind you that this snippet:

```
<physics type='ode'>
  <max_step_size>0.001</max_step_size>
  <real_time_factor>1</real_time_factor>
  <real_time_update_rate>1000</real_time_update_rate>
  <gravity>0 0 -9.8</gravity>
</physics>
```

is also Gazebo's default setting. The reason your RTF still goes below 1 is because your machine cannot handle it. Step size and update rate are pretty set in stone after they've been set. Real time factor however will be lowered if the machine cannot handle computing with the given parameters.

If you'd like achieve a real time factor of 1, you can follow the advice of linus111 and lower max_step_size and/or realt_time_update_rate. Note that this might change how certain elements behave in the Gazebo world as far as physics is conerned.

---

Originally posted by [Raskkii](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4131/raskkii/) with karma: 376 on 2017-12-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lursyy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/11648/lursyy/) on 2019-05-23**:
You meant to say *increase* max_step_size, didn't you? Otherwise, I would be confused.